# SplObjectStorage and sugary syntax in PHP

Tags: php, object, spl, key-value-store

Quick one; I doubt it's possible, but is there any way to take advantage of the `array($key => $value);` syntax of PHP with regard to `SplObjectStorage` objects?

What I mean is, is there any such way to achieve:

```
$store = // ?
    new KeyObject() => new ValueObject(),
    new KeyObject() => new ValueObject(),
    // ...
```

In the context initializing an object store? As of the moment I'm simply using: (*and will probably continue, considering the sheer unlikeliness of this being a possibility*)

```
$store = new SplObjectStorage();
$store[new KeyObject()] = new ValueObject();
$store[new KeyObject()] = new ValueObject();
// ...
```

Would be nice, highly doubting it, but maybe someone knows better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would be a more concise syntax, unfortunately it's not possible. The best you can do is either:

```
$store[new KeyObject()] = new ValueObject();
```

or

```
$store->append( new KeyObject(), new ValueObject());
```

When adding object to an `SplObjectStorage`.

Comment: Thanks @nickb - I figured as much; while expected, still unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like that:

```
$store = new SplObjectStorage();

$data = array(
    array(new KeyObject, new ValueObject),
    array(new KeyObject, new ValueObject),
    array(new KeyObject, new ValueObject),
);

foreach($data as $item) {
    list($key, $value) = $item;
    $store->attach($key, $value);
}
```

It's not beautiful but it's at least concise.

Comment: Thanks @vstm - I see what you mean, but I think I'll stick with the `$store[$obj] = $obj;` syntax if the one I proposed is unavailable. Nesting arrays like that, while "closer" syntactically to what I'm after, then necessitates iteration, or `array_map()`-ing to flatten it down.

Comment: The `array()` syntax will be slightly neater when 5.4 comes to play, using the short, square-bracket syntax supported for arrays.